# Coloring text inside ShowText as well as calling a variable?

Tags: javascript

Below is a code I referenced through some searching. The showText appears in a container on a page on via button toggle. I tried my best to find the solution for my problem but unfortunately i found nothing.

I'm trying to color the text inside the showText as well as call an input variable. Every time I try something it simply outputs it as a comment. I think there are different ways of doing this, but I'm still trying to learn JS. Advice would be helpful!

```
$('#gbutton').click(function () {
    $("#gjumbo").slideDown("slow");
    $("#gjumbo").slideDown(10000);
    $("#gjumbo").remove();
});

if (!$('#gbutton').click(function () {
    $("#acontainer").slideDown("slow");
    $("#acontainer").slideDown(10000);
})) {
}


 var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) {
        if (index < message.length) {
            $(target).append(message[index++]);
    //begin edit------------------------------|
            if (message[index] == '\n') {
                $(target).append("<br />");
            }
    //end edit--------------------------------|
            setTimeout(function () {
                showText(target, message, index, interval);
            }, interval);
        }
    };

    $(function () {
        showText("#msg", "test\nTest", 0, 20);
    });
```

Edit: HTML added.

```
<!-- Start-->
    <div id="acontainer" class="container">
        <div>
            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="display-4 text-center">Title</h1>
                   <div id="console" class="container">
                       <div class="container">
                           <div class="p-5" id="msg">
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End-->

 <div id="gjumbo" class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="display-4 text-center">H3 Title</h3>
            <p class="lead">Sample Paragraph</p>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text fas fa-user" id="user"></span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" aria-label="Username or Email"
                       aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required placeholder="Username or Email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>Sample Paragraph</p>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="formControlRange">Example Range input</label>
                <input type="range" class="form-control-range" id="formControlRange">
            </div>
            <button id="gbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Button</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: @Geshode Added in the edit :)

Comment: Added the slide code as well.

Comment: still have no idea what you want to achieve... maybe you can explain the step from enduser perspective in 1), 2), 3), etc....

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8eL6bc9z/ -- Here you go. Just click the button and the javascript will print out text going downwards. I want to be able to color specific words in that text, and call an input variable so I can capture the username inside that text. @Jerry

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your jsfiddle, i guess you want to do something like this:

1) load a list of user and display it in a `<div>`.

2) Highlight a specific user by index

3) When click on the user that loaded from (1), auto fill in to the username `<input type="text">`

If yes then you can refer to below code, i simplified the function, then you can move it to your code.

```js
function loadData(target,data){
 $(target).append(data)
}

//function colorUser(target,index){
//  let item = $(target + " #user" +index)
//  item.addClass("color")
//}

loadData("#msg","<div id='user1'>User 1</div><div id='user2'>User 2</div><div id='user3'>User 3</div><div id='user4'>User 4</div><div>User 5</div>")

//colorUser("#msg",2)

$("#msg div").on("click",(e)=>{
  $("#username").val(e.target.innerHTML)
})

$("#username").on("keyup",(e)=>{
  $("#fromInput").html(e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<style>
#msg div:hover{
  color:gray;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#msg div{
  color:blue;
}
</style>

<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="username">
<hr>

<div id="msg">
<h3>User Name List </h3>
<div id="fromInput"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not quite. I simply want to color the text in the showText code. Thats it. When the showText appears inside the container I want it to display the username the user inputted as well. https://jsfiddle.net/8eL6bc9z/2/ -- This is an example of the output that I would like to see. To be able to color any word inside the showText and to call the username into it as well so it outputs it. @Jerry

Comment: I changed my css selector to color all the text inside the `div` of `#msg`. All the username that inside `<div>` shall changed to blue color. Secondly,  i still don't understand what do you mean by `display the username the user inputted as well`. So, by guessing, i added one listener on the input, when user type something on the `text input`, the `something` will auto put into the username list. Just try to type something on the input.

Comment: Thank you Jerry but unfortunately the other member here provided something I was looking for. Sorry for being misunderstanding. Your code does help for my practices though.

Answer (score 0):

I change your `showText` function to show per word not letter (slow). Use `split("\n")` to split string separated by new line into array

```js
var username,
  userFound,
  userLists = "Testing\nTesting\nTesting\nONIS\nTesting\nTesting\nTesting".split('\n');

$('#gbutton').click(function() {
  userFound = false;
  $("#msg").html('');
  username = $('input[name=user]').eq(0).val();
  if (!username) {
    alert('username empty');
    return
  }
  showText("#msg", userLists, 0, 300);
});
var showText = function(target, message, index, interval) {
  if (index < message.length) {
    // begin coloring username
    if (message[index] == username) {
      $(target).append('<span style="color:yellow">' + message[index++] + '</span><br>');
      userFound = true;
    }
    // end coloring
    else {
      $(target).append(message[index++] + '<br>');
    }
    
    if (index >= userLists.length) {
      if (!userFound)
        $(target).append('<span style="color:yellow;font-weight:bold">Username Not found</span><br>');
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      showText(target, message, index, interval);
    }, interval);
  }
};
```

```css
div#console {
  background-color: #3e3d3d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="console" class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="p-5" id="msg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required placeholder="Username" value="ONIS">
<button id="gbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Button</button>
```

Comment: That is what I'm looking for except I don't want a set value for the username. I want it to output whatever a user inputs in the text field. I'm new to JS but I will try to figure it out. Don't want to be labeled as spoonfed here hah.

Comment: you mean autocomplete? if yes you need `input` event, in jQuery `$('input[name=user]').on('input' ,function(....`

Comment: I don't think so. This is a form. The user submits their username, i take it in, and i call it inside that showText.